# Dockerizing a Springboot app

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, kotlin, dockerfile

Context:
It's an application written in Kotlin and using Spring-boot with Maven.

Basically, I'd like to know if it makes sense what I'm doing.

Running `mvn install` then the `target` folder will be created with the corresponding `jar` file.
Therefore the Dockerfile will be just copying the `jar` file into the working directory of the container and run `java -jar WHATEVER.jar`.

Example of the simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY target/app-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 8089
CMD ["java", "-jar", "./app-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

But I'd say, makes much more sense to me to use the multi-stage building and in the first stage generate the `jar` file and in the second stage, execute it. I tried this second approach but I'm facing an issue with `main class doesn't exist`

Multi-stage Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine as BUILD

ENV APP_HOME=/usr/src/service
COPY ./src /usr/src/service
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/service
WORKDIR /usr/src/service
RUN mvn install
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/service/target/app-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "./app-DEV-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Which one is the correct one?

Comment: Does the jar exist at the expected location in the second step ?

Comment: Yes, the `.jar` is there as expected, and it's possible to execute it, but it says that the main class is missing. I'm not sure if it's something related to class-path, I'd like to know if someone else faced that issue.

Comment: Could you post the exact error? Is it failing on `mvn install` step or on application startup?

Comment: Sure: https://jpst.it/19S_c
It fails on app startup, when I try to run the docker container

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @snowe https://hastebin.com/depitidibo.xml

Comment: @IdirOuhabMeskine you shouldn't need to specify your mainClass if you are using the spring boot starters, but I am unable to replicate your problem using a sample app.. Is there any way you could provide your source code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the multistage dockerfile. Reason being you want to have least dependency on the host system. When you run mvn on host you add dependency of mvn and in turn java.

My recommendation would be to use multistage docker to build in one stage and copy to another stage

Comment: I've the same thoughts, but during the process, I couldn't fix the issue with the main class missing.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Can you try `mvn package` instead of install. Also can you create a new folder in your host with `src/ and pom.xml` only and see if the mvn works fine or not

Comment: Multistage v copying jar does not matter, since OP is using a maven docker container anyway it has the same result. Really he should be using the maven wrapper and then it would really not matter at all what system it is compiled on.

Comment: @snowe, The multistage docker file is copying only `src` and `pom.xml` inside the build container, I am not sure if that is what is causing the issue. Outside the docker it has the full folder

Comment: @TarunLalwani that shouldn't matter. I'm attempting to duplicate your issue locally so give me a few minutes.

Comment: oops tagged the wrong person in the last comment. I am unable to reproduce the issue. I would not suggest using a multistage build, due to the problems you will encounter as soon as you get to using multiple modules. You can resolve most issues you talked about by using a maven wrapper though